# ES2015: How can I simplify an if statement with assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React component that returns diverse tags based on a condition. The code is the following:

```js
// Header.jsx

import React from 'react';

const Header = ({...props}) => {
 let Tag;
 if (props.h1)
  Tag = 'h1';
 else if (props.h2)
  Tag = 'h2';
 else if (props.h3)
  Tag = 'h3';
 else if (props.h4)
  Tag = 'h4';
 else if (props.h5)
  Tag = 'h5';
 else
  Tag = 'h6';

 return (
  <Tag>
   { children }
  </Tag>
 );
}

export default Header;
```

I though ES2015 would support if as expressions, so I tried `let Tag = (if (expression) [...]);`, but it seems that it doesn't support. How can I simplify this snippet?

Comment: Can you keep the same key for `other` object

Comment: Sorry, but I disn't understand you.

Comment: Most of the times, `if else` chain and `switch` can be replaced by an object as follow `var tags = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h3',
    h4: 'h4',
    h5: 'h5'
};

var Tag = tags[other.heading];`

Comment: ES6 doesn't give us anything new, but standard ES5 simplification techniques apply

Comment: When you say "but it seems that it doesn't support", what do you mean by that? What errors do you get? What system are you using to run the code you show? And while I don't know anything about possible `if` expressions, it would be logical to think that if you have an `if` expression it *must* have an `else` part.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am compiling with Babel, and the compiler returns an error. And yes, it does have an *else*, it's part of the `[...]` elision.

Comment: @Tushar is spot-on, using a literal object (or a map, or a set if you want) is generally the way to simplify long conditions like those. However in that case you'd be better off simply storing the tag in a single property.

Comment: @IainGalloway Actually no. Tushar's example suggests that the object has a `heading` property, which is a String (`'h1'`, `'h2'`...). Using an object literal to map Strings to their own value is just dumb. Tushar gave a proof of concept requiring one property to rule them all, not an actual answer. Okay, strike that last one ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by dynamic searching for the tags with *regex*. The code ended like this:

```js
// Header.jsx

import React from 'react';

const Header = ({children, ...other}) => {
 let Tag = (() => {
  for(let key in other)
   if (/(h[1-6])/.exec(key)) return key;
  return 'h6';
 })();

 return (
  <Tag {...other}>
   { children }
  </Tag>
 );
}

export default Header;
```

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: My first thought: Please don't do this. Why do you use six different property names at all?

Comment: I have my reasons. When I use the Component I would write `<Header h1>` instead of `<Header level="h1">`, which is much easier, prettier and organized.

Comment: You really should consider using either `<H1>` (with subclasses?) or `<Header level=1>`. A boolean attribute just doesn't make sense. What happens if you do `<Header h4 h1 h3>`? In fact, with your `for in` loop, it's not even guaranteed that this expression would end with the same level every time.

Comment: It returns the first hx that it encounters.

Comment: I do not want to create six different components.

Comment: Yes, it returns the first matching property, but there is no guarantee that `h1` is the first - properties don't have an order. And six different components is not worse than six different properties - if you don't want 7 modules, use `<Header.h1>` etc.

Comment: I would not use more than one hx, só what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you *could* - that and the necessary loop over the properties hint at a design smell.

Comment: I don't see it as a problem, as I will not use more than one hx.

Comment: Sure, a design smell is not a problem in itself - it only leads to more complicated (and error-prone) code (like that loop). It will work fine, but it'll smell. Well, EOD, I guess you understand now what I think about this solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

For readability improvement I would say for-loop would be better:

```
let Tag;

for (let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) {
    if (Tag = props['h' + i]) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (which constitute an expression, not a statement like `if`, and can be used inside an assignment):

```
const Tag = props.h1
  ? 'h1'
  : props.h2
    ? 'h2'
    : props.h3
      ? 'h3'
      : props.h4
        ? 'h4'
        : props.h5
          ? 'h5'
          : 'h6';
```

Of course, the indentation might be improved (outdented to match `else if`), or you might want to use `&&` and `||` short-circuiting instead.

However, for what you are doing here I'd recommend to use a loop:

```
const Tag = (() => {
    for (let p of 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5'.split(','))
        if (props[p])
           return props[p];
    return 'h6';
})();
```

Or just store the tag name as a property itself next to the tag content, there's no reason to have 6 different properties for one thing:

```
export default function Header({children, headingLevel}) {
    const tag = 'h'+headingLevel;
    return (
        <tag>
            { children }
        </tag>
    );
}
```

Comment: I doesn't really simplify, it only let me use if as an expression.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, ternaries are the worst if you want to debug them.

Comment: @MateusFelipe: You asked for "*so I tried `let Tag = (if (expression) [...]);`, but it seems that it doesn't support.*", to which ternary operators are the answer. Of course, that's not necessarily the best solution.

Comment: @halfzebra: What's so wrong about them? Is your debugger not capable enough? And given that there are no side-effects here, this should really be no problem.

Comment: @Bergi Chrome DevTools debugger threats a bunch of embedded ternaries  as a single expression, making it harder to debug, like using single `var` or `let` for variable definitions. I agree, it **will work** for this specific case, but is that a simplification?

Comment: @halfzebra: Yes, I would consider it a simplification, because you are no more repeating the `Tag =` assignment. And yes, I would only nest ternaries for cases like this, where it *is* a variable definition :-)